# How can I get a video thumbnail in android if android can not decoding the video?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-ndk, thumbnails, video-thumbnails

I have successfuly get thumbnail for video with code like this:

`Bitmap bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(mediaFile.getAbsolutePath(),
                    MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);`

But this code can only get bitmap for few videos because android can not decode most part of videos for android video decoder is weak.

if I just want to get a thumbnail for video, do I have any good solution. If I do not need to use ndk is much better! But if ndk solution is much more efficient or easy, I think it also OK.

Answer (score 0):

You can use-

```
  MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
try {
   retriever.setDataSource(filePath);
   //here 5 means frame at the 5th sec.
    bitmap = retriever.getFrameAtTime(5);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
   // Assume this is a corrupt video file
}
```

Comment: In fact, you code is faced with the same problem like me. Android can not decode the video, so `retriever.getFrameAtTime` just return `null` for these video. In fact, a large part of video in my hand can not get bitmap.